# How to calculate vertex normals for a mesh in Java in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es

Can some one point me to Java code ( in Java not C or C++) that calculates all the normals for all the vertices of a mesh for OpenGL ES application. I need this for lighting. Lets say I have a cube with following vertices and indices:

```
float vertices[] = { -width, -height, -depth, // 0
                      width, -height, -depth, // 1
                      width,  height, -depth, // 2
                     -width,  height, -depth, // 3
                     -width, -height,  depth, // 4
                      width, -height,  depth, // 5
                      width,  height,  depth, // 6
                     -width,  height,  depth  // 7
        };
short indices[] = { 0, 2, 1,
                    0, 3, 2,
                    1,2,6,
                    6,5,1,
                    4,5,6,
                    6,7,4,
                    2,3,6,
                    6,3,7,
                    0,7,3,
                    0,4,7,
                    0,1,5,
                    0,5,4
                  };
```

In above specific example how many normals we need?

Comment: You need one normal per triangle. Calculating normals is covered here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/any-reliable-polygon-normal-calculation-code

Comment: @bummzack Is there a way in OpenGL-ES to only specify one normal per triangle? I thought you could only pass them in as a vertex attribute to your Vertex Shader (and do per vertex lighting). Right?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to set the normal per vertex. For a cube, all vertices of one side share the same normal though. Therefore you can calculate the normal once per side and then pass that to all vertices belonging to that side.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate normals by taking two edges, and cross product for each vertex. A cube actually has 24 vertices not 8, the reason is that each corner vertex is shared with different faces, because openGL takes per vertex attributes, you need to duplicate a vertex if you find that it has 2 different normals, assuming you want hard edges.

http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=1783

this is a C++ code but its self explanatory.